# Processing query parameters only if they exist and avoid showing some part of the page until then

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a Next.js registration form, which allows standard registration into the application. I also use this registration form to process invitations... The url for the standard registration form is `http://localhost/register`. But if there is an invitation, then the url is appended with an invite token like so: `http://localhost/register?token=afasdaqqeefef3d`.

What I am trying to do is check to see if the token exists, if it doesn't, then just display the standard registration form, but if there is a token present, it needs to send a request to see if the token is valid, if it is valid, prefill the email field with the invitation email address, but if it isn't valid, then display a message saying that the token is invalid.

The issue I'm having is that I can't seem to contact the API and retrieve the invite details in time when I load the page with a token, it displays the normal register form until it gets the data back from the api, and then the page changes.

I do have a page loader that displays a loading spinner, but it's just not working properly.

The code I currently have is as follows:

```
const Register = () => {
    const router = useRouter()

    const { register, isLoading } = useAuth({
        middleware: 'guest',
        redirectIfAuthenticated: '/dashboard',
    })

    const [inviteToken, setInviteToken] = useState('')
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState([])

    const submitForm = async event => {
        event.preventDefault()

        setLoading(true)

        try {
            await register({
                first_name: firstName,
                last_name: lastName,
            })
        } finally {
            setLoading(false)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (router.query.token?.length > 0 && errors.length === 0) {
            setInviteToken(router.query.token)
        }
    })

    if (router.query.token?.length > 0 && errors.length === 0 && inviteToken) {
        const { data: inviteData, error: inviteError } = useSWR('/api/retrieve-invite/' + router.query.token, () => 
            axios.get('/api/retrieve-invite/' + router.query.token)
                .then(response => response.data.data)
        )

        if (! inviteData) {
            return (<PageLoader />)
        }
    }

    if (isLoading) {
        return (<PageLoader />)
    }


    return (
     // rendering here
    )
}

export default Register
```

The error I keep getting is as follows;

```
Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call `useSWR` (a React hook) in an `if` statement, as you will be violating the [Rules of Hooks](https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning). The reason why you are getting that "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render" error. You can call `useSWR` [conditionally as explained here](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/conditional-fetching).

That has been said, find below a way to implement the behavior you looking for (notice how I simplified the overall logic, using the `isReady` prop of `useRouter`):

```
const Register = () => {
  const {
    query: { token },
    isReady,
  } = useRouter();

  const { register, isLoading } = useAuth({
    middleware: "guest",
    redirectIfAuthenticated: "/dashboard",
  });

  // Others hook calls...

  const {
    data: inviteData,
    error: inviteError,
    isLoading: loadingInviteData,
  } = useSWR(isReady && token ? "/api/retrieve-invite/" + token : null, () =>
    axios.get("/api/retrieve-invite/" + token).then((response) => response.data.data)
  );

  const submitForm = async (event) => {
    //....
  };

  if (isLoading || !isReady || loadingInviteData) {
    return <PageLoader />;
  }

  return "....";
};

export default Register;
```

Comment: Hey ... That seems to get rid of the error, but if i try and render a valid or not valid token message in my return, it doesnt show anyting `{!loadingInviteData && inviteData?.length > 0 && ( <p>I have a valid token</p>)}`

Comment: Are you sure `inviteData` is an array to use the `length`?

Comment: {
    "id": "234234234",
    "job_id": "323423423",
    "email": "email@here",
    "created_at": "2023-08-05T02:06:43.000000Z"
}

Comment: This is an object. You could change your condition to: `{inviteData && ( <p>I have a valid token</p>)}`

Comment: And for a not valid data: `{inviteError && ( <p>I have not a valid token</p>)}`